# get All the text fields data from the html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Get All the data values from the auto generated table  and show these values through loop to user by JavaScript alert.I have implemented but it is not showing anything in alert.how i can take the values from these autogenrated text fields.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var table1 = document.getElementById("myTable").length;
    var row   = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var textf1  = '<div>FirstName:<input type="text"  value="Enter Your Name" id="text1" /></div>';
    var textf2  = '<div>LastName:<input type="text"  value="Enter Your Surname" id="text2" /></div>';
    cell1.innerHTML = textf1;
    cell2.innerHTML = textf2;
}



function first(){
        var x = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var textn = "";
        var texts= "";
        var i;
        var a;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
            textn += text1[i].value + "<br>";
        }
        for (a = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
            texts += text2[i].value + "<br>";
        }
        alert("First Name:"+textn"Second Name:"+texts);

    /*var table1 = document.getElementById("myTable").length;
    for(var row = 0; row <= table1;row++ ) {
        alert("Hello" + text1.value(i) + "Your Surname Is " + text2.value(i) + " You Have Chosen");
    }
    /*return myFunction()*/
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myweb.js">

    </script>
</head>
<body>



<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

<table id="myTable"></table>
<table id="myTable1"></table>
<br>
<div id="first"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add Your First row</button>
<button onclick="first()">Submit</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you not using Jquery.. Can you create Jsfiddle for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function first(){
        var x = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var inputElements = x.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea');
        for(var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++){

             alert(inputElements[i].value);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert("First Name:"+textn"Second Name:"+texts);
```

Missing +

```
alert("First Name:"+textn+"Second Name:"+texts);
```